# Importing Java Object from computer to Android Studio

Tags: java, android, object, import

I'm working on an Android app project, and I have a major problem.
I need to import a java Object created and modified to the project. I serialized it on my computer and I need to read it and change the fields of my projects to the fields of the object that I serialized before.
I thought that I could try/catch the lines
`fileInputStream(..), readObject(..)`
But I obviously need to try/catch the whole code and particularly the `setContentView(..)` thing because it throws a `FileNotFoundException`.
Thus when I compile it on my phone, no errors but nothing happens. I think it happens because either the try{} isn't read or it can't read a file in OnCreate() from the computer..

How can I read a java Object from my computer in Android Studio ?
Thanks for helping

Comment: it's not clear what you are asking ?! do u want to access -from mobile app- a text file that is located on ur computer?

Comment: @Yazan I want to fill a static array color from a Java object I've serialized. This array will not change but it is complicated to fill in manually. When the user of the app enter a number (for instance 5), the textView sets its background to red because the fifth element of the array is red. Sorry, it is hard to explain..

Comment: you can -after serializing- that object to save in a text file and copy that file to `res/raw` or `assets` then from android app you can read and deserialize that object into a Java object and use it.

Comment: Thanks for answering I'll try this out